# Sitecore Url Rewrite Module map source url with out query string parameters to destination url with query string parameters

Tags: url-rewrite

I have a situation where i need to map a source url with out query string parameters to a internal destination url with query string, Lets say

**/pag1** to **/page2?Id=1**

is this possible? it work if i insert external link but not with internal, I have tried to modify the raw value of the link but with no luck.

**Update:**

Using IIS rewrite module is not an option as the content editor needs to change the maps frequently in Sitecore, without deploying a config change or recycling the app pool.

They update a .csv that contains the mapping, then run a command  which reads the .csv file entries, parse them, and create a corresponding mapping item in sitecore.

Answer (score 6):

This is possible with the IIS rewrite module. This example comes from the Microsoft iis.net site:

to rewrite **http://localhost/pag342**
to: **http://localhost/page2?id=342**

you would need find a pattern by using a regular expression 
`(^pag/([0-9]+)` (this finds 342) and redirect it using an action:

```
page2?id={R:1}
```

A detailed guide on *exactly* your problem can be found here: https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: thanks Bas. but IIS rewrite module is not an option as the content editors need to change the rewrite frequently without deploying a config change or recycling the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

There is this Sitecore module for URL Rewrite https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Url_Rewrite.aspx that should do a good job for you.

And also editors have access to edit the rules, as every setting is inside Sitecore as an Item. Plus this:

> In addition to adding Site specific redirect capabilities, I have
>   modeled the data structure to closely match the functionality of
>   Microsoft's IIS Url Rewrite plugin.

So you should be able to have a rule that covers your needs.